# Has anyone done a migration from Rackspace to AWS yet and if yes how did you achieved it

Tags: amazon-web-services, rackspace-cloud

I have quite a few servers in Rackspace and I wanted to migrate them over to AWS without any third party tools. Has anyone managed to achieve this yet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Rackspace has a Fanatical AWS offering. As an AWS premier partner, Rackspace can help you migrate from a Rackspace infrastructure to an AWS infrastructure without having to give up Rackspace's Fanatical Support. In addition you can take advantage of a team of certified core architects to help insure you are taking advantage of best practices in security, redundancy, resiliency, etc.

Yes, you are reading this correctly :) Rackspace can help you migrate off of Rackspace infrastructure. With this offering you get the best of AWS and Rackspace together.

More info can be found here: https://www.rackspace.com/managed-aws.

Disclaimer: I work for Rackspace as the AWS Evangelist and an AWS certified Solution Architect.

Hope this helps!!